# Type Family Type Hackery

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to write a fairly polymorphic library. I've run into a situation that's easier to show than tell. It looks a bit like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

class Format f where type Target f
class Format f => Formatter x f where
  target :: forall y. Formatable y => Target f -> x -> y
class Formatable y where name :: y -> String

instance Formatable Integer where name = show
instance Formatable Int where name = show

split :: forall x f. (Format f, Formatter x f) => x -> f -> String -> [Either String (Target f)]
split = undefined

display :: forall x f. (Format f, Formatter x f) => f -> String -> x -> String
display f str x = let
  chunks = split x f str
  built = foldr apply "" chunks
  apply (Left s) accum = accum ++ s
  apply (Right t) accum = accum ++ name (target t x)
  in foldr apply "" chunks
```

Essentially, we have polymorphic `Format`s, which define a number of `Target`s. There are also a number of `Formattable` objects, which know how to respond to a bunch of different format options (reduced here to simply `name`).

These `Formattables` are composed in a variety of ways, and can respond to a number of different targets. `Formatter`s are essentially the router between `Format` and `Formattable` -- given a target (from a specific format) they respond with a suitable `Formattable` object.

This is all pretty abstract. Here's an example:

- `DateFormat` specifies targets like `Year`, `Month`, and `Day`.
- `MonthType` is a `Formattable` newtype of `Int` that has names such as "February"
- There is also the simple `instance Formattable Int where name = show`
- `DateTime` might be a type synonym for `(Int, MonthType, Int)`.

(Obviously, I've cut out a lot of machinery here, such as piping the correct values around, but you get the idea.)

The `display` function is fairly simple. It takes a formatter, a string specifying the format, an object to display, and renders it all into a string.

First it breaks the string up into targets and strings. For example, a date formatter might break the string `"%Y-%m-%d"` into `[Right Year, Left "-", Right Month, Left "-", Right Day]`. The `split` function does that, and has been redacted here.

The `display` function simply tracks down the `Formattable`s for each target and accumulates the string.

Or, at least, it`s supposed to.

But it fails typechecking with the following error:

```
Reduced.hs:20:16:
    Could not deduce (Target f ~ Target f0)
    from the context (Format f, Formatter x f)
      bound by the type signature for
                 display :: (Format f, Formatter x f) => f -> String -> x -> String
      at Reduced.hs:(19,5)-(24,30)
    NB: `Target' is a type function, and may not be injective
    Expected type: [Either [Char] (Target f0)]
      Actual type: [Either String (Target f)]
    In the return type of a call of `split'
    In the expression: split x f str
    In an equation for `chunks': chunks = split x f str
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

and I can't for the life of me figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Target f` does not determine `f`, which means that the function

```
target :: (Formatter f x, Formatable y) => Target f -> x -> y
```

can never be called. No matter what type annotation you give to `target`, you can't nail down what `f` is, and so the compiler can never figure out which `Formatter` instance to use. I'm not 100% sure, but probably the solution is not to use multi-parameter type classes and to let one of `x` or `f` be a function of the other. Also, you should probably just delete the `Format` class entirely (did you know you don't need a class to use a type family?). Perhaps something like this:

```
class Formatter x where
    type Format x
    target :: Formatable y => Format x -> x -> y
```

Comment: I'm still stuck. Even if I omit the type family and the `Format` class entirely (and just use `class Ord f => Formatter x f where target :: forall y. f -> x -> y`) then it fails with the following:


Reduced.hs:23:40:
    Ambiguous type variable `y0' in the constraint:
      (Formatable y0) arising from a use of `name'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `name (target t x)'
    In the expression: accum ++ name (target t x)
    In an equation for `apply':
        apply (Right t) accum = accum ++ name (target t x)

Comment: @So8res The error is unreadable inline, but it looks like a new error at least. Perhaps make a new question for it?

Comment: Hrm. It is. My apologies. I can get around the error by creating a `Box` data type for all `Formatable`s. Not the most elegant solution, but it will work for now.

Comment: @So8res instead of `type Format x` you might want to use `data Target x`.  Data families (as opposed to type families, which you've used so far) are injective, meaning that the compiler can deduce `f` from `Target f`.